# Detecting collisions in SpriteKit, objects with the same bit mask?

Tags: sprite-kit

I am new to SpriteKit and cannot seem to figure out how to detect collisions between two or more objects that have the same bit mask. In my game, cars enter the scene from left/right and top/bottom. I need to be able to track when cars are crashing for scoring purposes. Right now, cars  intersect and crash (Car1 from left/right Car2 from top/bottom) but not cars that are in the same lane (Car1 from left Car2 from left with higher speed). Instead they end up just driving through one another. Here's the code:

First I setup the bit masks at the beginning of Car.m:

```
typedef enum : NSUInteger {
    vehicleCategory         = (1 << 0),
    environmentCategory     = (1 << 1),
} NodeCategory;
```

EDIT: Note: Right now I am not testing for collisions between cars and the environment, the environmentCategory is there for future use.

Next is spawnCarWithColor: andSpeed: screenEdge: afterDelay: andScale:

```
- (Car*)spawnCarWithColor:(NSUInteger)color andSpeed:(NSUInteger)speed screenEdge:(NSUInteger)screenEdge afterDelay:(CGFloat)delay andScale:(CGFloat)carScale {

    NSArray *carColorsAssets = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"blueCar", @"redCar", @"greenCar", nil];

    carColorsForDisplay = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"blue", @"red", @"green", nil];

    edgeOfScreenForDisplay = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"left", @"top", @"right", @"bottom", nil];

    Car *newCar = [Car spriteNodeWithImageNamed:[carColorsAssets objectAtIndex:color]];


//    set CGPath for phyics

    CGFloat offsetX = newCar.frame.size.width * newCar.anchorPoint.x;
    CGFloat offsetY = newCar.frame.size.height * newCar.anchorPoint.y;

    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();

    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, 0 - offsetX, 24 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 0 - offsetX, 21 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 0 - offsetX, 18 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 1 - offsetX, 16 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 1 - offsetX, 13 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 3 - offsetX, 11 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 5 - offsetX, 8 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 6 - offsetX, 6 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 8 - offsetX, 5 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 11 - offsetX, 3 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 14 - offsetX, 3 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 16 - offsetX, 3 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 18 - offsetX, 3 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 20 - offsetX, 3 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 23 - offsetX, 3 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 25 - offsetX, 3 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 28 - offsetX, 3 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 29 - offsetX, 3 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 34 - offsetX, 4 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 37 - offsetX, 4 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 40 - offsetX, 4 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 44 - offsetX, 4 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 48 - offsetX, 4 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 50 - offsetX, 4 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 54 - offsetX, 4 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 56 - offsetX, 4 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 60 - offsetX, 3 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 63 - offsetX, 3 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 66 - offsetX, 3 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 69 - offsetX, 3 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 72 - offsetX, 3 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 74 - offsetX, 3 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 77 - offsetX, 3 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 80 - offsetX, 3 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 83 - offsetX, 3 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 86 - offsetX, 3 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 88 - offsetX, 3 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 91 - offsetX, 4 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 93 - offsetX, 6 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 95 - offsetX, 7 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 96 - offsetX, 10 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 97 - offsetX, 12 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 98 - offsetX, 15 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 98 - offsetX, 18 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 98 - offsetX, 21 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 98 - offsetX, 24 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 98 - offsetX, 26 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 98 - offsetX, 29 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 98 - offsetX, 32 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 97 - offsetX, 35 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 96 - offsetX, 39 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 95 - offsetX, 41 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 93 - offsetX, 44 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 90 - offsetX, 45 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 85 - offsetX, 46 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 81 - offsetX, 46 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 76 - offsetX, 46 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 72 - offsetX, 46 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 67 - offsetX, 46 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 63 - offsetX, 46 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 58 - offsetX, 46 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 53 - offsetX, 46 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 47 - offsetX, 46 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 42 - offsetX, 46 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 39 - offsetX, 46 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 35 - offsetX, 46 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 31 - offsetX, 46 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 27 - offsetX, 46 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 23 - offsetX, 46 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 19 - offsetX, 46 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 16 - offsetX, 46 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 12 - offsetX, 46 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 8 - offsetX, 45 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 5 - offsetX, 43 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 3 - offsetX, 40 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 1 - offsetX, 35 - offsetY);

    CGPathCloseSubpath(path);

    newCar.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithPolygonFromPath:path];
    newCar.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = vehicleCategory;
    newCar.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = vehicleCategory;
    newCar.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = vehicleCategory;
    newCar.physicsBody.restitution = 1.0;
    newCar.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
    newCar.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = TRUE;
    newCar.scale = carScale;
    newCar.zPosition = 2;
    newCar.carColor = [carColorsForDisplay objectAtIndex:color];
    newCar.edgeOfScreen = [edgeOfScreenForDisplay objectAtIndex:screenEdge];
    newCar.vehicleType = @"car";

    switch (screenEdge) {
        case 0:
            newCar.zRotation = M_PI;
            newCar.position = CGPointMake(-100, 512);
            carVelocity = CGVectorMake(speed, 0);
            leftEdgeCarTotal++;
            carName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"left%i", leftEdgeCarTotal];
            [leftEdgeCars addObject:carName];
            newCar.name = carName;
            newCar.edgeOfScreen = @"left";
            break;

        case 1:
            newCar.zRotation = M_PI/2;
            newCar.position = CGPointMake(352, 868);
            carVelocity = CGVectorMake(0, -speed);
            topEdgeCarTotal++;
            carName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"top%i", topEdgeCarTotal];
            [topEdgeCars addObject:carName];
            newCar.name = carName;
            break;

        case 2:
            newCar.position = CGPointMake(1124, 545);
            carVelocity = CGVectorMake(-speed, 0);
            rightEdgeCarTotal++;
            carName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"right%i", rightEdgeCarTotal];
            [rightEdgeCars addObject:carName];
            newCar.name = carName;
            break;

        case 3:
            newCar.zRotation = -0.5*M_PI;
            newCar.position = CGPointMake(415, -100);
            carVelocity = CGVectorMake(0, speed);
            bottomEdgeCarTotal++;
            carName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"bottom%i", bottomEdgeCarTotal];
            [bottomEdgeCars addObject:carName];
            newCar.name = carName;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    newCar.physicsBody.velocity = carVelocity;

    NSLog(@"Spawned a %@ %@ from the %@, Speed of %i after a %g sec delay", [carColorsForDisplay objectAtIndex:color], newCar.vehicleType, [edgeOfScreenForDisplay objectAtIndex:screenEdge], speed, delay);

    return newCar;

}
```

Is there a way to detect when two cars collide that are in the same lane? Right now my didBeginContact is pretty bare bones; just some NSLog statements about the nodes and their attributes. I've learned a lot from here, I am stoked I actually have a question to ask now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKPhysicsBody/bodyWithPolygonFromPath:) for `SKPhysicsBody`, the `path` parameter for the `bodyWithPolygonFromPath:` method is described as:

"A **convex** polygonal path with counterclockwise winding and no self intersections. The points are specified relative to the owning node’s origin."

Please make sure the path you are creating adheres to the description given above.

Here's a [link](http://www.mathopenref.com/polygonconvex.html) to the definition of convex polygons.

Comment: Thanks guys, the path was a little ridiculous after reading about how to set it up properly. After cleaning that up, collisions are working great.